# attach Quad to top of figure in Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, tooltip, bokeh

As Bokeh does not support tooltips for BoxAnnotations, my workaround is to add a Quad to the figure and attach a HoverTool to the Quad. How could I make the quad always span from the top to the bottom of the figure, regardless of the zooming?

Comment: I'd suggest adding zoom bounds to the range (assuming here that infinite zoom-out is not useful) and then make the quad taller than that. See e.g. http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d

Comment: @bigreddot how can I prevent the (initial) figure's Y-axis to scale with the data and not with the Quad? Or should I calculate the bounds precisely on the data+little margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `DataRange1d` ranges have a `renderers` property that you can set to explicitly list the renderers that should be auto-ranged over. In this case you can set it to leave out the quad:

```
from bokeh.models import BoxAnnotation
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure()

r = p.circle([1,2,3], [2,5,3])

p.quad(left=1.5, right=2.5, top=10e8, bottom=-10e8, alpha=0.2)

# add in all the renderers except the quad
p.y_range.renderers = [r]

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reviving this question. The project is dead already but I'll keep this for further use.